# add a local variables to a function

Tags: python

is it possible to add a local varible to a function, just before calling it ? if yes how ?

EDIT:REASON
i noticed that all my views in django are using

```
render_to_response(template_name,locals())
```

now i created a middleware and i wanted to add one more local variable using the

```
def process_view():
```

method of it .so that i don't have to modify the views .

Comment: Can you give more details? What are you really trying to do?

Comment: You want to add a local variable to a function from outside the function? Sounds like an extremely stupid idea. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: There is no point in doing this, since the function has no code that refers to that variable. Why would you think you want to do this? Please edit your question to clarify so that a better answer can be given.

Comment: No. If you explain why you want to do this rather than simply pass a parameter, then maybe someone can offer a solution.

Comment: Its seems that anything is possible in Python - one question though, what would you do with it if you could?

Comment: .. and thats why using `locals()` is a bad idea to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i mangaged to do that using decorators.

Comment: Which means you didn't update locals, you passed in arguments or manipulated the return value.

Comment: this is not an answer

Answer (score 7):

The local scope for a function does not exist until the function is called, so it's not possible to do this. You *could* do this for a closure, but the next person to have to maintain the code would hunt you down and kill you.

Answer (score 1):

Although I also think it is pretty useless, I thought that you may enclose the function in either a 'with' statement or another function, like the code below. Of course, this approach can be accomplished directly within the function of interest. In fact, you are adding the local variable 'during' the function declaration. See if this fits your needs!

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def my_funct(_local):
    """My function of interest
    """
    print "Local argument was %s" % str(_local)
    return "Finished"

def localize(fct, local_var):
    """
    """
    return fct(_local = local_var)

## Use function to 'localize' variable
localize(my_funct, local_var="LOCAL_VARIABLE")

## Same effect without supplementary function :
my_funct(_local="LOCAL_VARIABLE")

try:
    print local_var
except:
    print "No such global variable"
```

Just some thoughts :)

Cheers

Comment: That's not adding a local variable, that's just passing in a value as an argument.

Comment: @Matti: Hum, it is passing an argument that exists nowhere else in the global namespace, so in effect, it declares the value for a local variable outside the body of the function, but still hidden from the global namespace. Like I said, those are just some thoughts inspired by the OP's question. Cheers!

Comment: Adding "just some thoughts" to everything is a great way to explicitly state that you do not claim that what you said is relevant or useful. Have you considered a career as a politician?

Comment: Tell me, should I commit sepuku right away??? I have made the observation that sometimes when a user puts in his 2 cents, without satisfyingly answering the question, it sprouts a useful discussion or even digression. Not so with my reply, apparently, as you so nicely take time to highlight. The above code was just an attempt at following the line of thought proposed by the question to where my own understanding of Python could take me. I hope I'll be useful to someone someday :) Cheers.

Comment: Hey, no need to start committing seppuku, my comment was just some thoughts.

Comment: You see me reassured! The cost of those one of those wakizashi short swords is prohibitive, plus I don't know anybody with enough experience to assist me... (be kind enough not to propose yourself)

Answer (score 0):

> So if you’re one of those lazy
>   programmers and you like keeping code
>   particularly concise, you can take
>   advantage of a built-in Python
>   function called locals(). It returns a
>   dictionary mapping all local variable
>   names to their values, where “local”
>   means all variables that have been
>   defined within the current scope.
>   [source](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter04/)

It is a trick in order to not have to explicitly list all of the variables you need to pass in to the function. In this case, you need to explicitly state a variable to pass in. Therefore, you should not be using `locals()` in the calls you are making in your middle-ware, as the trick was not designed to be used like that.

Comment: trick ? i guess thats a perfectly normal use of the function locals() , and i guess it probably is not possible to modify it outside the fucntion or atleast before the function call. :( :(

Comment: The site I linked to specifically refers to it as a trick. Basically it is a simple way to achieve the goal you want that may not be immediately obvious. I think the fact that it may share more variables than you require is what keeps it a "neat trick" rather than a "best practice". Unless your template is very careful, it could alter a variable and effect code in the caller's scope.